# Freemarker replace

Tags: regex, freemarker

Here's

```
<#elseif  (pageData.author.googlePlus)[0]=="+" || (pageData.author.googlePlus)?  
 matches("^[+]+")>
<#assign str = (pageData.author.googlePlus)?replace("^[+]+","")>
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/+${(str)!}/posts" />
<#else>
```

What's wrong in this? I want something like this

```
Input:  +xyz 
Output: +xyz

Input:  ++xyz
Output: +xyz

Input:  +++xyz
Output: +xyz
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are missing the `"r"` parameter. Do it like this: `?replace("^[+]+", "", "r")`

Answer (score 0):

Insert the ^ inside the caracter class [] :

`[^+]+`

Result:

```
+++xyz
Match 1:    xyz      3       3
```

> Characters that are not within a range can be matched by complementing
>   the set. If the first character of the set is '^', all the characters
>   that are not in the set will be matched. For example, [^5] will match
>   any character except '5', and [^^] will match any character except
>   '^'. ^ has no special meaning if it’s not the first character in the
>   set.

at https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html